# Repair Spells/Infusions and "Constructs"

Tags: dnd-3.5e, artificer

I've been having a bit of an argument with another DM lately over whether the Artificer's Repair infusions can effect inanimate objects.

From my understanding, RAW the repair spells are only meant to effect **creatures** with the Construct subtype, not "constructs" in the general sense of "anything constructed".

Am I correct in thinking that Repair Damage spells are only supposed to "heal" construct characters and not capable of repairing an inanimate object such as a door or wagon?

Answer (score 2):

By the official rules, yes, you are correct: “Construct” refers to “Construct-type creatures.”

I would say that there is no harm in allowing *repair light damage* et al. to repair objects as well, but I would houserule that specifically; there are likely cases where reading “Construct” as including constructed objects will cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

## You're Correct

The spell *repair light damage* [trans] (*ECS* 114) says, in part,

> When laying your hands upon a **construct** that has at least 1 hit point remaining, or a **living construct** with –9 or more hit points, you transmute its structure to repair damage it has taken.

A [construct](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#constructType) "is an animated object or artificially constructed creature" (*MM* 306).
A living construct "is a created being given sentience and free will through powerful and complex creation enchantments... [and] combine[s] aspects of both constructs and living creatures" (*ECS* 23).

What that DM's describing is the effects of either the spell *mending* [trans] (*PH* 253) or *make whole* [trans] (*PH* 252) or another similar spell.